# Not deleting data from Email select Box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, email

I have working script which is sending emails from website to some array of emails.

**Problem is:** If the user forgot to choose value from select box (value = email to mail@mail.com in PHP array) my script is throwing alert "Choose a value!" but all data wrote by the user will be deleted from all select boxes.

Is there any way to avoid it?

JS:

```
function formSubmit() //onclick "Submit" button
{
    var selectedValue  = document.getElementById("sendTo").value;  

    if(selectedValue="99")
    {
        alert("Choose a value!");
    }
    else
    {
        //working ajax script which is sending emails
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<label class="company_emails">
    <select id="sendTo">
        <option value="99">Choose a department</option>
        <option value="0">Justice</option>
        <option value="1">Injustice</option>
        <option value="2">Potatoes</option>
        <option value="3">Mushrooms</option>
    </select>            
</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to stop the submit when there is an error, otherwise the form will be submitted and is empty again.

```
function formSubmit() {
    var selectedValue  = document.getElementById("sendTo").value;  

    if( selectedValue == "99" ) {
        alert("Choose a value!");

        // return false will stop the submit
        return false;
    }
}
```

But if you do it with `onclick` on a button you have to use return there too:

```
<button type="submit" onclick="return formSubmit();">send</button>
```

Or even better, if you have jQuery available, just register a listener on the form submit and use `preventDefault`. This is the best way imo.

```
$("form").on("submit", function(e) {
    if( $("#sendTo").val() == "99" ) {
        alert("Choose a value!");

        // will stop the submit
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

And as user @Carr said, you have missed a `=` in your `if` statement.

Comment: thx bro that works perfectly :) must wait few minutes and accepting your answer.

Comment: No problem @Carr. I've missed that error in my answer before, so I've noted your response there. :)

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function formSubmit() //onclick "Submit" button
{
    var selectedValue  = document.getElementById("sendTo").value;  

    if(selectedValue="99")
    {
        alert("Choose a value!");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        //working ajax script which is sending emails
    }
}
</script>
```

And need to have return keyword on-click method of button as below.

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return formSubmit()"/>
```